# Streaming Contract pending transactions using ethers?

Tags: contract-invocation, ethers.js, pending-transactions

Trying to setup interaction with a contract to stream pending transactions but I don't see how to do so for a specific contract or address. Ethers js documentation shows how to pull all pending tx (which in theory, could work if filtered for specified address) however, there must be a better way to accomplish this.

A sample of my code:

```
  let addressToWatch = "0x.....89"

  let myFilter = {
      address: "addressToWatch",
      fromBlock: 'pending',
  }

  customWsProvider.on(myFilter, (log, event) => {
      console.log(log);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this article by Quicknode
https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-stream-pending-transactions-with-ethersjs